# How to use import this npm package?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, meteor

I want to import [this](https://github.com/reactjs/react-chartjs) package.

The link only provide this example

```
var LineChart = require("react-chartjs").Line;

var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
   return <LineChart data={chartData} options={chartOptions} width="600"         height="250"/>
 }
});
```

but how to import like this

```
import {LineChart } from 'react-chartjs';
```

I can not figure out how to

> .Line;

in import style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the answer from oxy_js, I believe the import line you want is

```
import { Line as LineChart } from 'react-chartjs';
```

This is import `Line` but alias it as `LineChart` for use in this file.

Answer (score 3):

```
var LineChart = require("react-chartjs").Line;
```

Equivalent

```
import Line from 'react-chartjs/lib/line';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write

```
import Line from 'react-chartjs';
```

Because in `index.js` of `react-chartjs` Line is listed as

```
module.exports = {
  Bar: require('./lib/bar'),
  Doughnut: require('./lib/doughnut'),
  Line: require('./lib/line'),
  Pie: require('./lib/pie'),
  PolarArea: require('./lib/polar-area'),
  Radar: require('./lib/radar'),
  createClass: require('./lib/core').createClass
};
```

And then use `{Line}` when you need.